# Weird python list syntax with an attribute

Tags: python, list, syntax, minecraft

I'm currently learning python by writing filters for the MCedit  python program, a 3D block editor for Minecraft.
Filters are small pieces of code that can be ran inside the program, as a function.

One of the functions given by MCedit allows to exctract a schematic (here named temp) to modify it. In the demo, the creator of the program modify the block attribute of the schematic, by the following line :

```
temp.blocks[temp.blocks == 14] = 52
```

The .blocks attribute is made of concatenated lists, on 3 layers (x, y, z).

This piece of code replaces any of the value in any of the lists being equal to 14 by 52.

I tried to make it change other values, with:

```
temp.blocks[temp.blocks == 14 or temp.blocks == 15] = 52
```

but it simply doesn't work.

I know there are other ways to do it, but this one being particularely simple, compact and efficient, I'd like to understand how it works.

Comment: This looks a lot like NumPy. Is `temp.blocks` actually made of nested lists, or is it a NumPy ndarray?

Comment: @user2357112: I do see `numpy` dependencies in the editor source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the underlying `blocks` class has replaced the *normal* semantics of various Python expressions to implement a mini query language.

Most likely, the `blocks` class overrides the [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) and [`__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) hooks.

The `temp.blocks == 14` expression is handled by the `__eq__` hook and returns *some* kind of specialized object that is then passed to the `__setitem__` hook via the `[...]` syntax. The `__setitem__` hook then uses that specialised object to determine what indices in the sequence to alter.

The `==` operator looks for a `__eq__` method on either operand, and if present, that method is called and the return value (normally `True` or `False`) is returned as the result for that equality test. However, the `__eq__` method on `temp.blocks` returns something *else*; and that 'something' could also implement additional hooks (such as `__or__` and `__and__`) to make further refinements to the query language possible.

The `temp.blocks[expr1] = expr2` assignment is translated to `blocks.__setitem__(expr1, expr2)`, so the outcome of `blocks.__eq__(14)` is passed to that method for it to alter the underlying sequence based on the 'search query'.

At a guess, `temp.blocks[temp.blocks == 14 | temp.blocks == 15] = 52` *could* also work, provided the special object implements the [`__or__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__); it may implement the [`__and__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__and__) to make `&` work as well.

The reason `|` and `&` could be supported is that `or` and `and` are not overridable with hooks (these short-circuit, a hook would require both operands to be evaluated *breaking* short-circuit expectations).

Comment: To elaborate, `or` is not overrideable in Python (neither is `and`) because it short-circuits, and so the second argument might not actually need to be evaluated; however, calling a method would require both arguments to be evaluated before the call. There was a proposal to change that ([PEP 335](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/#rejection-notice)) but it was rejected. This is why you might need to use the arithmetic or, `|`, instead.

Comment: @kindall: yup, elaborated in the answer to cover that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I think I understood most of it, sad it's not some sort of secret list syntax I've never heard before. However, both | and & returns a ValueError, saying that I should use a.all() or a.any(), so I guess he didn't implemented multiple statement compatibility.

Comment: @user2657597: You most likely have `numpy.ndarray` objects then. See http://www.numpy.org/

Comment: I used type () on temp.blocks, and it did return numpy.ndarray, however, the documentation doesn't mention that kind of list building.

Comment: @user2657597: `==` on a `array` or `ndarray` returns an array of booleans (`True` and `False`) indicating matching indexes. Pass that in as an item index (either to get or assign) and it becomes a list of indices to select.

Comment: So I need to combine the two array of booleans beforehand into a new array, is that right? Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: Hrm, the return type is a `numpy.ndarray() with `dtype=bool`; I'll look for an `or` operation on `ndarray` instances..

Comment: And I did find a mention of the boolean mask operations here: http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/numpy.html#using-boolean-masks and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Comment: Ah, just use the second mask as a mask on the *first* mask: `equals_14 = temp.Blocks == 14` then `equals_14[temp.Blocks == 15] = True` sets all matching indices to `True`, effectively combining the two masks.

Comment: That's what I used until now, I just wanted to know if what turned out to be masks were more powerful or not. Turns out & works if you add parenthesis. So a[(a != 1) & (a != 2)] will work fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2657597: ah, indeed, `ndarray` objects have a `__or__` method.